# SQL Inner join more than two tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I can currently query the join of two tables on the equality of a foreign/primary key in the following way.

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` 
                         INNER JOIN 
                       `table2` ON table1.primaryKey=table2.table1Id");
```

I'd like to extend this to multiple tables (all with the same foreign keys). I am trying the following code which is not returning anything. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` 
                        INNER JOIN `table2` 
                        INNER JOIN table3 
                        ON table1.primaryKey=table2.table1Id=table3.table1Id");
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
      ON table1.primaryKey=table2.table1Id
INNER JOIN table3
      ON table1.primaryKey=table3.table1Id
```

Comment: Can someone please help me on this? Is this the same as `SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.primaryKey=table2.table1Id AND table1.primaryKey=table3.table1Id`?

Answer (score 34):

Here is a general SQL query syntax to join three or more table. This SQL query should work in all major relation database e.g. MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQLServer, Sybase and PostgreSQL :

```
SELECT t1.col, t3.col FROM table1 join table2 ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey
                                  join table3 ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey
```

We first join table 1 and table 2 which produce a temporary table with combined data from table1 and table2,  which is then joined to table3. This formula can be extended for more than 3 tables to N tables, You just need to make sure that SQL query should have N-1 join statement in order to join N tables. like for joining two tables we require 1 join statement and for joining 3 tables we need 2 join statement.

Comment: Clearest answer I could find. Great example of the structure.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT eb.n_EmpId,
   em.s_EmpName,
   deg.s_DesignationName,
   dm.s_DeptName
FROM tbl_EmployeeMaster em
 INNER JOIN tbl_DesignationMaster deg ON em.n_DesignationId=deg.n_DesignationId
 INNER JOIN tbl_DepartmentMaster dm ON dm.n_DeptId = em.n_DepartmentId
 INNER JOIN tbl_EmployeeBranch eb ON eb.n_BranchId = em.n_BranchId;
```

Comment: this is the example of  joining of 4 tables in mysql/sql...hope you will get correct result..thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
SELECT Company.Company_Id,Company.Company_Name,
    Invoice_Details.Invoice_No, Product_Details.Price
  FROM Company inner join Invoice_Details
    ON Company.Company_Id=Invoice_Details.Company_Id
 INNER JOIN Product_Details
        ON Invoice_Details.Invoice_No= Product_Details.Invoice_No
 WHERE Price='60000';
```

-- tets changes

Answer (score 0):

The [right syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213227%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.primaryKey = table2.ForeignKey
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.primaryKey = table2.ForeignKey
```

Orthe last line joining table3 on table1 like:

```
ON table3.ForeignKey= table1.PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Employee inner join [Order] 
On Employee.Employee_id=[Order].Employee_id
inner join Book 
On Book.Book_id=[Order].Book_id
inner join Book_Author
On Book_Author.Book_id=Book.Book_id
inner join Author
On Book_Author.Author_id=Author.Author_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find inner join for more than 2 table here

Here are 4  table name like

1. Orders
2. Customers
3. Student
4. Lecturer

So the SQL code would be:

```
select o.orderid, c.customername, l.lname, s.studadd, s.studmarks 
from orders o 
    inner join customers c on o.customrid = c.customerid 
    inner join lecturer l  on o.customrid = l.id 
    inner join student s   on o.customrid=s.studmarks;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method given below, modify to suit your need.

```
SELECT
  employment_status.staff_type,
  COUNT(monthly_pay_register.age),
  monthly_pay_register.BASIC_SALARY,
  monthly_pay_register.TOTAL_MONTHLY_ALLOWANCES,
  monthly_pay_register.MONTHLY_GROSS,
  monthly_pay_register.TOTAL_MONTHLY_DEDUCTIONS,
  monthly_pay_register.MONTHLY_PAY
FROM 
  (monthly_pay_register INNER JOIN deduction_logs 
ON
  monthly_pay_register.employee_info_employee_no = deduction_logs.employee_no)
INNER JOIN
  employment_status ON deduction_logs.employee_no = employment_status.employee_no
WHERE
  monthly_pay_register.`YEAR`=2017
and 
  monthly_pay_register.`MONTH`='may'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select WucsName as WUCS_Name,Year,Tot_Households,Tot_Households,Tot_Male_Farmers  from tbl_Gender
INNER JOIN tblWUCS
ON tbl_Gender.WUCS_id =tblWUCS .WucsId 
INNER JOIN tblYear
ON tbl_Gender.YearID=tblYear.yearID
```

There are 3 Tables 
1. tbl_Gender 
2. tblWUCS 
3. tblYear

Answer (score -2):

## Try this Here the syntax is

```
SELECT table1 .columnName, table3 .columnName 
   FROM table1 
     inner join table2 
          ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey 
     inner join table3 
          ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey
```

for example:
*`Select SalesHeader.invoiceDate,ActualSales,DeptName,tblInvDepartment.DeptCode ,LocationCode from SalesDetail Inner Join SalesHeader on SalesDetail.InvoiceNo = SalesHeader.InvoiceNo inner join tblInvDepartment on tblInvDepartment.DeptCode = SalesDetail.DeptCode`*

Comment: This is good... it does the general version and not specific to a table.

Comment: Isn't this just Harjeet's answer with different indentation?