# MS Access Inner Join On 3 Tables with the same field_name

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2013

I'm doing an assignment for class, and I'm at my whits end. Basically, I need to write a query that uses `INNER JOIN`'s to combine all the data in 4 tables, while avoiding having titles columns with identical names (Ie `Table1.Master_Number` and `Table2.Master_Number`). The literal instructions are as follows:

**Step 1:**  Create a view of all the columns (only list the columns once if the columns are duplicated in the tables) in all the tables of the Lecture 5 database.  Save this query as Lecture_5_View and us this query to build the following 3 queries.  In the “FROM” clause, you MUST use an “INNER JOIN” in this query. Remember ACCESS does not support the “CREATE VIEW” command so you must create a select query. `

Here is a screenshot of the database, that shows all the headings and column headings.
[image: Tables]

Based on other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables), I thought that it would be pretty simple. I have this so far, but it does not want to run

> (ie Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'Table1.Master_Number = Table2.Master_Number INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table1.Master_Number = Table4.Master_Number)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Master_Number = Table2.Master_Number
INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table1.Master_Number = Table4.Master_Number
```

Where am I going wrong so far and how to I accomplish this query?

Much thanks,
Josh

Comment: What error do you get when trying to run it?

Comment: What does `does not want to run.` mean?  Does it give you an error?

Comment: And never again use select *. Very bad practice especially if you have joins. PLus you need to list the columns if you want to pass the instructions not to repeate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Access you need to use parentheses when doing more than one join:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (Table1 
        INNER JOIN Table2 
            ON Table1.Master_Number = Table2.Master_Number)
        INNER JOIN Table4 
            ON Table1.Master_Number = Table4.Master_Number;
```

This is essentiall spliting down you query so you have at most one join per section, i.e. Your First query is:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1
        INNER JOIN Table2
            ON Table1.Master_Number = Table2.Master_Number;
```

Then you have:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourFirstQuery
        INNER JOIN Table4 
            ON Table1.Master_Number = Table4.Master_Number;
```

This differs slightly from subqueries as you are still able to reference all fields from Table1 and Table2.

---

**EDIT**

To avoid duplicating columns you will need to explicitly list the columns you want ([although you should be doing this anyway](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)):

```
SELECT  Table1.Master_Number,
        Table1.Asset_Tag,
        Table1.Serial_Number,
        Table2.Last_Name,
        Table2.First_Name,
        Table4.Office_Number,
        Table4.Location,
        Table4.Department
FROM    (Table1 
        INNER JOIN Table2 
            ON Table1.Master_Number = Table2.Master_Number)
        INNER JOIN Table4 
            ON Table1.Master_Number = Table4.Master_Number;
```

Comment: That worked, but it gives me `Table1.Master_Number`, `Table2.Master_Number`, and `Table4.Master_Number`. I think its supposed to be just one column named `Master_Number`.

Comment: I thought I would have to explicitly list them, but I wasn't entirely sure. Thanks for the clarification. Lastly, I would need another `INNER JOIN` for `Table1.Asset_Tag` and `Table3.Asset_Tag`, correct?

Comment: Yes, you would just need to add another set of parentheses around the joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM ((Table1
  INNER JOIN Table2 
  ON Table1.Master_Number = Table2.Master_Number)
  INNER JOIN Table4 
  ON Table1.Master_Number = Table4.Master_Number)
```