# Joining multiple tables for a webapp

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have 10 tables of player statistics and I would like to JOIN them all so I can display a statistic leaders table in my web application.  I am new to this and I know a JOIN would work for two tables but is there a way of joining 10 tables?

Thanks

Comment: Joining 10 tables does not sound good, specially when you are new. Yes it is same like joining 2 tables

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes... But its a very expensive query to call and you should try to limit the amount of joins