# Joining Two SQL Tables That share a many to one Realtionship

Tags: mysql, relational-database, inner-join

Hi I have two tables one named **Team** and the other named **Schedule**.

The Schedule table has the following attributes: `id`, `away`, `home`, `date`... where away and home are foreign keys to the Team table.

The Team table has the following attributes: `name` and `id`.

My goal is to join Team and Schedule so that schedule.id, away, awayTeamName, home, homeTeamName, date are all in the same query. This is what i have so far

```
SELECT  `GAME_ID` ,  `AWAY` , TEAM.NAME AS awayName,  `HOME`,  `LEVEL` , 
`LOCATION` ,  `DATE` 
FROM SCHEDULE
INNER JOIN TEAM ON SCHEDULE.AWAY = TEAM.TEAM_ID
OR SCHEDULE.HOME = TEAM.TEAM_ID
```

and the output i get is something like this

```
GAME_ID | AWAY | awayName | HOME | LEVEL | LOCATION | DATE
1       | 2    |  name1   | 3    |varsity| @home    | 06/22/2015
```

But I want it to look like this

```
GAME_ID | AWAY | awayName | HOME | homeName| LEVEL | LOCATION | DATE
1       | 2    |  name2   | 3    | name3   |varsity| @home    | 06/22/2015
```

If anybody can help i would appreciate it

Comment: You need another `INNER JOIN` with `Team` table (use different aliases).

Comment: Can you provide the data? You only show your desired result but your source data is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have more than one join.

```
SELECT  SCHEDULE.GAME_ID , away.AWAY, away.NAME AS awayName, home.HOME , home.NAME AS homeName, LEVEL , 
LOCATION , DATE 
FROM SCHEDULE
INNER JOIN TEAM as away ON SCHEDULE.AWAY = TEAM.TEAM_ID INNER JOIN TEAM as home ON
SCHEDULE.HOME = TEAM.TEAM_ID
```

It will be something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INNER JOIN TEAM as home ON SCHEDULE.HOME = TEAM.TEAM_ID
```

add this to the end of your query,this gives you two inner joins which is perfectly legal.

you should be able to find this useful whenever you have more than two tables to deal with in the future.

[inner joins on more than 2 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables)