# Query between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

`images` - image_id .. etc

`users` - user_id .. etc

`favs` - user_id, image_id

So now I want when user log into his account and click on button `My favs` to show all his favs. What would be the query to mysql here?

Comment: Did you try building a query? If yes, post it.

Comment: this is either a duplicate of [combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields) or [sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables)

Comment: I'm not. I don't know how exactly. What JOIN to use, why to use that join, how exactly joins work. What I want? So I will need to select all `images` that are in `favs` and where `user_id=1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select images.image_id, ... from images
inner join favs on images.image_id = favs.image_id
inner join users on users.user_id = favs.user_id
where users.user_id = [...]
```

If you don't need any data from `users` then the last join is not necessary and you can change the last line to `where favs.user_id = [...]`

This might help you understand which joins do what:
[image]

Comment: i've got error on this join `inner join favs on images.user_id = favs.image_id` ->` Unknown column 'images.user_id' in 'on clause'` .. I don't have user_id column in table `images`

Comment: **@John**: change `images.user_id = favs.image_id` to `images.image_id = favs.image_id`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the query to `inner join favs on images.image_id = favs.image_id`

Comment: Tried that and didn't work also. But like this is working `images.image_id = favs.user_id`