# How to join more than two levels of join in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have below tables

1.student(student_id,student_name)

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+
| student_id | Student_name |   class   |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|          1 | A            | 5TH GRADE |
|          2 | B            | 5TH GRADE |
|          3 | C            | 5TH GRADE |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

2.student_subject_link(student_id,subject_id)

```
+------------+------------+
| student_id | subject_id |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |        400 |
|          2 |        401 |
|          1 |        401 |
|          2 |        403 |
|          3 |        400 |
|          3 |        401 |
+------------+------------+
```

3.subject(subject_id,subject_name),

```
+------------+-----------------+
| subject_id |  subject_name   |
+------------+-----------------+
|        400 | MATHS           |
|        401 | PHYSICS         |
|        402 | CHEMISTRY       |
|        403 | COMPUTERSCIENCE |
|        404 | ENGLISH         |
+------------+-----------------+
```

4.student_file(student_id,file_id,file_name,file_uploaded_by,file_updated_by)

```
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| STUDENT_ID | FILE_ID | FILE_NAME | FILE_CREATED_BY | FILE_UPDATED_BY |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|          1 |     500 | FILEA.TXT | STAFF1          | STAFF2          |
|          2 |     501 | FILEB.TXT | STAFF2          | STAFF2          |
|          3 |     502 | FILEC.TXT | STAFF3          | STAFF2          |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

5.staff(staff_id,staff_name)student_file and staff table are linked by staff_id.file_uploaded_by ,file_created_by has staff_id.

```
+----------+------------+
| STAFF_ID | STAFF_NAME |
+----------+------------+
| STAFF1   | XX         |
| STAFF2   | YY         |
| STAFF3   | ZZ         |
+----------+------------+
```

I need to get the below output. Is it possible to achieve this in a single query or do i have to use multiple queries (one for getting subject id and other for file details. I am using this in a spring web application. Can you please let me know the best way to achieve this.

I want to join all those tables to take student_name,List of Subjects he enrolled(comma separated field),file_name,File created by(Staff name from staff table),File Updated by(Staff name from staff table)

```
+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| STUDENT_NAME |         SUBJECT         | FILE_NAME | FILE_CREATED_BY | FILE_UPDATED_BY |
+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|            1 | MATHS,PHYSICS           | FILEA.TXT | XX              | YY              |
|            2 | PHYSICS,COMPUTERSCIENCE | FILEB.TXT | YY              | YY              |
|            3 | MATHS,PHYSICS           | FILEC.TXT | ZZ              | YY              |
+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Looks like homework, and that is OK, but you need to show some effort.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
WITH sub AS
  (SELECT student_id,
          LISTAGG(subject_name, ',') WITHIN
   GROUP (
          ORDER BY subject_id) SUBJECT
   FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT sbl.student_id,
                      sb.subject_id,
                      subject_name
      FROM student_subject_link sbl
      JOIN subject sb ON sb.subject_id = sbl.subject_id )
   GROUP BY student_id )
SELECT stu.student_name,
       MAX(sub.subject) SUBJECT,
       MAX(sf.file_name) FILE_NAME,
       MAX(
             (SELECT stf.staff_name
              FROM staff stf
              WHERE stf.STAFF_ID = sf.FILE_CREATED_BY )) FILE_CREATED_BY,
       MAX(
             (SELECT stf.staff_name
              FROM staff stf
              WHERE stf.STAFF_ID = sf.FILE_UPDATED_BY )) FILE_UPDATED_BY
FROM student stu
JOIN sub ON sub.student_id = stu.student_id
JOIN student_file sf ON sf.student_id = stu.student_id
GROUP BY stu.student_name;
```

*EDIT:*

**Explanation** ( Requested by OP)  : `student_subject_link` and `student` are related by subject_id. But since the relation is many to many, The operation of concatenation of enrolled subjects is taken in a separate with clause and not included in the joins involving main tables to avoid confusion. `LISTAGG` function concatenates elements within a group.`Distinct` is used to avoid duplicates formed because of join.  A `with` clause helps us to construct an inline view which can be reused as if it was a table.

In the select clause , since we need to group by student_name, `MAX` of all other values are taken which are required for the group by to work. A correlated sub query in select is used to  fetch the corresponding `staff_name` since it cannot be inner joined because of one to many relation.