# Joining two tables without a common column but using another table connected to both

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in Mysql

- table A-> uid, itemType, balance,orderType
- table B-> orderId, itemType, qty
- table C-> uid,orderId

I need to get (balance-qty) for every uid:orderIdcombination for specific type of item. How can I connect table A and table B if they have no common column to join on. But both of them are connected to table C.

Comment: You can join all three in one SELECT statement. You'd have two JOIN clauses. See [SQL inner join more than two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With joins between the 3 tables:

```
select a.uid, a.balance, b.qty
from tablea a 
inner join tablec c on c.uid = a.uid
inner join tableb b on b.orderid = c.orderid
where a.itemtype = ?
```

You can add more columns if you need them.