# How to Use Multiple Join on Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, inner-join

I have these following Classes:

```
class Person(){
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
   private List<PersonRoles> roles;
}

class PersonRoles(){
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
   private Person person;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "request_id")
   private Request request;
}

class Request(){
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="request")
   private List<PersonRoles> roles;
}
```

Now I am going to fetch all person based on a given request id and his roles by using hibernate and inner join but my log is telling me that my table doesn't exist. This is my query so far:

```
sql = "SELECT p.* FROM person AS p INNER JOIN p.roles ON p.roles.personId = p.id 
INNER JOIN request AS r ON p.roles.requestId = r.id AND p.roles.role like :item 
AND r.id = :id";
query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Person.class);
query.setParameter("item", "Members");
query.setParameter("id", id);
person = (Person) query.uniqueResult();
```

and this is what i received on the log:

```
Table 'p.roles' doesn't exist
```

Did i forget some hibernate annotation? or My query has something wrong?

Comment: It's because you wrote an SQL (native). No mapping is used.

Comment: How to convert it to fully hibernate sir?

Comment: You would have to use entities instead of table names, here is an example: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-named-query

Comment: I tried something like this but it gives me a *null*: ```sql = "from Person as p inner join p.roles as roles inner join roles.request as request  where roles.role like :item and request.id = :id";```

Answer (score 0):

**Brief reason**

your syntax of SQL is wrong

**Detailed explanation**

here is the syntax of inner join [example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

for [multiple inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
      ON table1.primaryKey=table2.table1Id
INNER JOIN table3
      ON table1.primaryKey=table3.table1Id
```

but you have used `INNER JOIN p.roles` there should be a table name after the INNER JOIN, not a column name.

that's why you got an error, moreover, use HQL instead of SQL in hibernate it is a good practice.

*happy coding!*

Comment: I tried to use HQL but i got null. ```sql = "from Person as person inner join person.roles as roles inner join roles.request as request where roles.role like :item and request.id = :id"```

Comment: your syntax is wrong friend, "inner join person.roles" this is wrong

Comment: you can not join a column, try to join another table

Comment: even in HQL? I already used the Class not the table. Person class has many association with class Roles.

Comment: yes, hql is not a magic, it change the code to sql so you should follow the SQL rules and requlations

Comment: use a class and post the error details, then i can suggest a solution

Comment: use "query = session.createQuery(hql); " for hql

Comment: ```sql = "from Person as person inner join person.roles as roles inner join roles.request as request where roles.role like :item and request.id = :id";
Query q = session.createQuery(sql);
q.setParameter("item", "Members");
q.setParameter("id", id);
person = (Person) q.uniqueResult();```

Comment: I already used ```query = session.createQuery(sql)``` but i got null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191398/discussion-between-anirudh-lou-and-majuran).